# toLocalString not the same as string when comparing

Tags: javascript, typescript, intl

I am comparing two strings with a currency that seems to be the same.
One is created with toLocaleString() and the other by declaring a static string.
Both put out the same value on the console, but every compare method fails for them.

Any idea why this is not working? This is blowing my mind!
I am not sure if it is the euro symbol...

```js
const localStringValue = (2).toLocaleString('de', {style: 'currency', maximumFractionDigits: 2, currency: 'EUR'});
const stringValue = '2,00 €';

console.log('local string: ', localStringValue);
console.log('string: ', stringValue);

console.log('strict compare', localStringValue === stringValue);
console.log('compare', localStringValue == stringValue);
console.log('locale compare', localStringValue.localeCompare(stringValue));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value and currency is separated by non-breaking space in `localStringValue`, but in `stringValue` it's normal space.

```js
const localStringValue = (2).toLocaleString('de', {
  style: 'currency',
  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
  currency: 'EUR'
});
const stringValue = '2,00 €';

console.log('local string: ', localStringValue, encodeURIComponent(localStringValue));
console.log('      string: ', stringValue, encodeURIComponent(stringValue));
```

Comment: Oh man.. I spent 3h on this and thought it would be the euro symbol, because with GBP format it worked ('£2.00')! But so it is the space/nbs that hits it!!
Thank you so much!!! <3

Comment: Do you have a link to the Information you gave?

Comment: @Franki1986 according to the specification this function is implementation-defined  https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-number.prototype.tolocalestring